# ReactNative Facebook Login Issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, facebook-login

I followed the steps here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-ios) for facebook login with iOS. I'm using a custom login call from my own component. The login confirm dialog comes up fine but when I hit "Continue" mobile safari seems to get stuck:

[image]

I'm seeing a bunch of weird warnings:

: -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

requesting pasteboard fb_app_attribution
Apr 12 08:08:42 MacBook-Pro pasted[69862] : ...requesting pasteboard fb_app_attribution completed. Error: (null)
Apr 12 08:08:56 SafariViewService[70243] : Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service

But none really yield any good search results. Any help would be amazing. Thanks.

P.S. My code for calling login:

```
  handleFacebookPress() {
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']).then(
  (result) => {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      console.log('Login was cancelled');
    } else {
      console.log('Login was successful with permissions: '
        + result.grantedPermissions.toString());
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log('Login failed with error: ' + error);
  }
);
```

}

Comment: IIRC the `fbauth2` URL is applicable to the Facebook mobile app. Is it inatalled on your phone/simulator? Also, what do your own log prints show?

Comment: Also, have you initialized the SDK with your app ID?

Comment: @YSK, I do not have the FB app installed on the sim. The logging never gets hit. I did init the SDK. It shows up correctly and I can hit continue. Then it hangs up. Thanks!

Comment: Have you followed the configuration steps at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix it by adjusting the Oauth url in the facebook application portal to be https://localhost:8081 as my react native localhost was using port 8081